# the rely of modbus4j

Tags: java, modbus

The rely of modbus4j is

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.infiniteautomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>modbus4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

now I also need a SeroUtils, but I cant find it in maven resp
https://mvnrepository.com/

except:

```java
  import com.serotonin.modbus4j.serial.SerialParameters;
  ...
  SerialParameters serialParameters = new SerialParameters();
  serialParameters.setCommPortId("COM3");
  serialParameters.set...
```

what is the rely of SeroUtils?

---

sorry, i realize i dont need a SeroUtils, now i need the SerialPortWrapper
except:

```java
 ModbusFactory factory = new ModbusFactory();
 /*
 * need a wrapper
 */
 ModbusMaster master = factory.createRtuMaster(wrapper);
```

so how can I set a wrapper?

---

https://github.com/infiniteautomation/modbus4j/issues/5 
this solve my question

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `pom.xml` to include their repository. It is not on maven central.

Add this to your `<repositories>` section:

```
<repository>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>ias-snapshots</id>
    <name>Infinite Automation Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://maven.mangoautomation.net/repository/ias-snapshot/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>ias-releases</id>
    <name>Infinite Automation Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://maven.mangoautomation.net/repository/ias-release/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: my pom.xml already has it, and i dont know how to set paramters into ModbusFactory

Comment: When you said `but I cant find it in maven resp` that made your question look like the `<repository>` was missing. Can you update your post to be more specific?

Comment: update , i find the factory has changed the construction , now i need a wrapper